# Set Magento Attribute to Configurable Product with Soap API

Tags: api, soap, magento, magento-1.4

I need to create a new configurable product via  Magento Soap API and add a related product to it.

I use this code that create 2 products ( one simple and one configur. ) then i try to link the simple one to the config one...this don't work..
There is a tutorial for do that??
Any help??
Many thanks.

```
// Magento login information 
    $mage_url = 'http://test.de/api/?wsdl'; 
    $mage_user = 'admin'; 
    $mage_api_key = 'admin'; 
    // Initialize the SOAP client 
    $soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url ); 
    // Login to Magento 
    $session = $soap->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );



    $attributeSets = $soap->call($session,'product_attribute_set.list');
    $set = current($attributeSets);

    $sku = 'iphone-12345';

    //configurable

    $newProductData = array(
        'name'              => 'iPhone',
        'websites'          => array(1),
        'short_description' => 'short description',
        'description'       => 'description',
        'price'             => 150,
        'status'            => '1',
        'categories'    => array(138),
    );



    $newProductRelated = array(

        'name'              => 'iPhone',
        'websites'          => array(1),
        'short_description' => 'short description',
        'description'       => 'description',
        'price'             => 150,
        'status'            => '1',
        'sku'               => '2551464'
            );



    $productId = $soap->call($session,'product.create',array('configurable', $set['set_id'], $sku ,$newProductData));
    $productId2 = $soap->call($session,'product.create',array('simple', $set['set_id'], $newProductRelated['sku'] ,$newProductRelated));




    $soap->call($session, 'product_link.assign', array('configurable', $sku, $newProductRelated['sku'], array('position'=>0, 'colore'=> 21, 'qty'=>6)));
```

mant thx again.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with a similar issue and resorted to using the CSV import to create the relation for products imported from the API.  This may may be a usable approach for a one time import via a generated CSV.